# How can I change this condition <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PUT_URL_HERE"'>

Tags: conditional-statements, blogger, blogspot

How can I change that condition with my custom title like this `<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:blog.title/></a>`

with the put url with the >>  /search?updated-max=2013-12-20T18:37:00-08:00&max-results=3

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PUT_URL_HERE"'>

<style>

.body-fauxcolumn-outer .cap-top {
position: absolute;}



</style>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://YOUR-BLOG-URL/search?updated-max=2013-12-20T18:37:00-08:00&max-results=3&quot;'>
<style>

.body-fauxcolumn-outer .cap-top {
position: absolute;}

</style>
</b:if
```